# What is the quickest way to HTTP GET in Python?

Tags: python, http, networking

What is the quickest way to HTTP GET in Python if I know the content will be a string? I am searching the documentation for a quick one-liner like:

```
contents = url.get("http://example.com/foo/bar")
```

But all I can find using Google are `httplib` and `urllib` - and I am unable to find a shortcut in those libraries.

Does standard Python 2.5 have a shortcut in some form as above, or should I write a function `url_get`?

1. I would prefer not to capture the output of shelling out to `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: I thought I would pass this along, as it had me stumped for hours. I tried getting the text that visually appeared in the browser, but instead got snippets of a web app. The solution was to go into the browser Developer Tools, click on the Network tab, and reload the page. In the list of files that came over the network, I could see the text file I wanted. I could right-click on it and "Open in new tab" to verify.

Answer (score 1005, accepted):

Python 3:

```
import urllib.request
contents = urllib.request.urlopen("http://example.com/foo/bar").read()
```

Python 2:

```
import urllib2
contents = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/foo/bar").read()
```

Documentation for [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.request.html) and [`read`](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

Comment: Does everything get cleaned up nicely? It looks like I should call `close` after your `read`. Is that necessary?

Comment: It is good practice to close it, but if you're looking for a quick one-liner, you could omit it. :-)

Comment: For what it's worth, the same thing works with urllib in place of urllib2 (at least for most URLs).

Comment: The object returned by urlopen will be deleted (and finalized, which closes it) when it falls out of scope. Because Cpython is reference-counted, you can rely on that happening immediately after the `read`. But a `with` block would be clearer and safer for Jython, etc.

Comment: It doesn't work with HTTPS-only websites. `requests` works fine

Comment: If you're using **Amazon Lambda** and need to get a URL, the 2.x solution is available and built-in. It does seem to work with https as well.  It's nothing more than `r = urllib2.urlopen("http://blah.com/blah")` and then `text = r.read()`. It is sync, it just waits for the result in "text".

Comment: What are the pros / cons compared to `requests`?

Comment: See [should I call close() after urllib.urlopen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1522636/52677510) for the explanation in details.

Comment: @sah Consider posting that on the linked question above if you think it's useful.

Comment: Technically 'contents' is a 'bytes' object, not a 'str'. You need the right encoding to convert it into a str; this is challenging to extract from the content. I've tried assuming utf-8 (eg contents = str(contents, 'utf-8'), but hit errors on web pages that claim they're utf-8. So this remains confusing/ambiguous... But for most cases we can treat the bytes as a string, so I guess that's good enough.
I tried contents = str(contents) too, but this has the disadvantage of turning '\n' characters into separate slashes and ns. ('\\n').

Comment: @ApolloGrace you can use the `errors` parameter for decode (ignore or replace might be helpful). See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

Answer (score 510):

Use the [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://example.com/foo/bar")
```

Then you can do stuff like this:

```
>>> print(r.status_code)
>>> print(r.headers)
>>> print(r.content)  # bytes
>>> print(r.text)     # r.content as str
```

Install Requests by running this command:

```
pip install requests
```

Comment: Almost any Python library can be used in AWS Lambda. For pure Python, you just need to "vendor" that library (copy into your module's folders rather than using `pip install`). For non-pure libraries, there's an extra step -- you need to `pip install` the lib onto an instance of AWS Linux (the same OS variant lambdas run under), then copy those files instead so you'll have binary compatibility with AWS Linux. The only libraries you won't always be able to use in Lambda are those with binary distributions only, which are thankfully pretty rare.

Comment: @lawphotog this DOES work with python3, but you have to `pip install requests`.

Comment: Even the urllib2 standard library recommends requests

Comment: In regards to Lambda:

if you do wish to use requests in AWS Lambda functions. There is a preinstalled boto3 requests library also.

`from botocore.vendored import requests`

Usage

`response = requests.get('...')`

Comment: @kmjb borrowing requests from botocore has been deprecated https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/ and--imo--it's a bad idea to rely on indirect dependencies

Answer (score 31):

If you want solution with httplib2 to be oneliner consider instantiating anonymous Http object

```
import httplib2
resp, content = httplib2.Http().request("http://example.com/foo/bar")
```

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at [httplib2](https://github.com/httplib2/httplib2), which - next to a lot of very useful features - provides exactly what you want.

```
import httplib2

resp, content = httplib2.Http().request("http://example.com/foo/bar")
```

Where content would be the response body (as a string), and resp would contain the status and response headers.

It doesn't come included with a standard python install though (but it only requires standard python), but it's definitely worth checking out.

Answer (score 17):

It's simple enough with the powerful `urllib3` library.

Import it like this:

```py
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
```

And make a request like this:

```
response = http.request('GET', 'https://example.com')

print(response.data) # Raw data.
print(response.data.decode('utf-8')) # Text.
print(response.status) # Status code.
print(response.headers['Content-Type']) # Content type.
```

You can add headers too:

```
response = http.request('GET', 'https://example.com', headers={
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2'
})
```

More info can be found on the [urllib3 documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/).

`urllib3` is much safer and easier to use than the builtin `urllib.request` or `http` modules and is stable.

Comment: great for the fact you can easily provide an HTTP verb

Answer (score 15):

Actually in Python we can read from HTTP responses like from files, here is an example for reading JSON from an API.

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(url) as f:
    resp = json.load(f)

return resp['some_key']
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Comment: This is an old request/answer but I found value in this because it has the elegant `with...` syntax that I could just grab.

Comment: This question adds value as it uses the with construct which is much discussed in the comments on the top-voted and accepted answer, yet lacking from it.

Answer (score 9):

Without further necessary imports this solution works (for me) - also with https:

```
try:
    import urllib2 as urlreq # Python 2.x
except:
    import urllib.request as urlreq # Python 3.x
req = urlreq.Request("http://example.com/foo/bar")
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36')
urlreq.urlopen(req).read()
```

I often have difficulty grabbing the content when not specifying a "User-Agent" in the header information. Then usually the requests are cancelled with something like: `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` or `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

Comment: Unexpectedly, the 'User-Agent' for Microsoft Edge really is something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10136` according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591706/what-is-the-user-agent-string-name-for-microsoft-edge. Not sure how to find out the most recent `Microsoft Edge UA string`, but the answer here rightly hints at the way to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

**How to also send headers**

Python 3:

```
import urllib.request
contents = urllib.request.urlopen(urllib.request.Request(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/releases/latest",
    headers={"Accept" : 'application/vnd.github.full+json"text/html'}
)).read()
print(contents)
```

Python 2:

```
import urllib2
contents = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(
    "https://api.github.com",
    headers={"Accept" : 'application/vnd.github.full+json"text/html'}
)).read()
print(contents)
```

Answer (score 6):

theller's solution for wget is really useful, however, i found it does not print out the progress throughout the downloading process. It's perfect if you add one line after the print statement in reporthook.

```
import sys, urllib

def reporthook(a, b, c):
    print "% 3.1f%% of %d bytes\r" % (min(100, float(a * b) / c * 100), c),
    sys.stdout.flush()
for url in sys.argv[1:]:
    i = url.rfind("/")
    file = url[i+1:]
    print url, "->", file
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, file, reporthook)
print
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a wget script in Python:

```
# From python cookbook, 2nd edition, page 487
import sys, urllib

def reporthook(a, b, c):
    print "% 3.1f%% of %d bytes\r" % (min(100, float(a * b) / c * 100), c),
for url in sys.argv[1:]:
    i = url.rfind("/")
    file = url[i+1:]
    print url, "->", file
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, file, reporthook)
print
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a lower level API:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('example.com')
conn.request('GET', '/')

resp = conn.getresponse()
content = resp.read()

conn.close()

text = content.decode('utf-8')

print(text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Excellent solutions Xuan, Theller.

For it to work with python 3 make the following changes

```
import sys, urllib.request

def reporthook(a, b, c):
    print ("% 3.1f%% of %d bytes\r" % (min(100, float(a * b) / c * 100), c))
    sys.stdout.flush()
for url in sys.argv[1:]:
    i = url.rfind("/")
    file = url[i+1:]
    print (url, "->", file)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file, reporthook)
print
```

Also, the URL you enter should be preceded by a "http://", otherwise it returns a unknown url type error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with HTTP APIs specifically, there are also more convenient choices such as [Nap](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/nap).

For example, here's how to get gists from Github since *May 1st 2014*:

```
from nap.url import Url
api = Url('https://api.github.com')

gists = api.join('gists')
response = gists.get(params={'since': '2014-05-01T00:00:00Z'})
print(response.json())
```

More examples: https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/nap#examples

Comment: You should mention that you are the author of this library.

Answer (score 1):

For `python >= 3.6`, you can use [dload](https://pypi.org/project/dload/):

```
import dload
t = dload.text(url)
```

---

For `json`:

```
j = dload.json(url)
```

---

Install:
`pip install dload`

Comment: The OP wanted to make a GET request WITHOUT using a library, while this solution requires you to install a package using pip and import the library.

Comment: @YılmazAlpaslan OP asked for no such thing, that was an edit someone made to the title of the question that I have rolled back. The actual problem with this answer is it's recommending some weird library that no one is using.

Comment: As far a I understood, the op asked for the "_quickest way to HTTP GET in Python_" , based on that, you can use the `dload` library, even if not many users use it, something that's not a requirement for an answer. Just a guess, but I don't think you understood the question properly, but reading other answers may giving you clue because many different libraries are also recommended.