# How to close urllib2 connection?

Tags: python, connection, urllib, ddos

I have made a program using urllib2 that makes a lot of connections across the web. I noticed that eventually that this can be DDoS worthy; I would like to know how to close down each connection after I have done my business to prevent such an attack.

The code I am using to open a connection is:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
r = opener.open("http://www.python.org)
html = r.read()
```

Comment: Look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522636/should-i-call-close-after-urllib-urlopen  but pay attention to 2nd and 3rd answers which are more accurate.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you are opening them with the `urlopen()` function. [Its documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) states:

> This function returns a file-like object with two additional methods:

As a file-like object, it will have a `close` method which you can call:

```
connection = urllib2.urlopen(url)
# Do cool stuff in here.
connection.close()
```

**Update**: Using the code you added to your question:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import cookielib
>>> cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
>>> r = opener.open("http://www.python.org")
>>> html = r.read()
>>> r.close??
Type:  instancemethod
Base Class: <type 'instancemethod'>
String Form: <bound method addinfourl.close of <addinfourl at 150857644 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x8fd48ec>>>
Namespace: Interactive
File:  /usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py
Definition: r.close(self)
Source:
    def close(self):
        self.read = None
        self.readline = None
        self.readlines = None
        self.fileno = None
        if self.fp: self.fp.close()
        self.fp = None
```

So the `close()` method exists and actually does something:

```
>>> r.close()
>>> r.read()
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: @nobody - not on my machine. I updated my answer to use the code you added to your question.

Answer (score 2):

your question is extremely vague.

but here is an example of closing a connection after use:

```
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: Close is not defined; there has to be some other proper way.

Comment: close() is defined on the urlopen return (file-like object)

Comment: the close is just `def close: pass`

Comment: @Senthil Kumaran - not on my machine (Ubuntu 10.10/Python 2.6.6) it isn't. The comment formatting will make this a bit hard to read, but on my machine it does ``self.read = None; self.readline = None; self.readlines = None; self.fileno = None; if self.fp: self.fp.close(); self.fp = None`` i.e., it closes the underlying file object and overwrites the read methods with ``None`` so they cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

The socket connection closes automatically, once the response is obtained. So you don't explicitly close the urllopen object, it happens automatically at the socket level.

Comment: No it doesn't. Set up a connection: ``conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/')``, and then check the status of the socket: ``print conn.fp.closed`` which will print ``False`` as you'd hope. Read the data: ``devnull = conn.read()``, and now check the status of the socket: ``print conn.fp.closed`` which still prints ``False``, i.e., the socket is still open.

Comment: Admittedly it may be different on your operating system / Python version, but this just goes to show you cannot rely on this happening implicitly. Explicit is better than implicit...

Comment: The connection actually is closed whenever you `read()` the response, you can verify this by looking at the `read()` method of `HTTPResponse`, using `netstat`, etc.