# Python Better network API than urllib

Tags: python, network-programming

I noticed there is no way to close connections in urllib (close does not work). Is there a better more robust network API for python?

Comment: Define "better" and "robust".

Comment: And related to better: what are you trying to do with the API

Answer (score 4):

You are not alone with the problems of urllib. Python community has come up with few alternatives

Try here:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests

Requests is sane API over urllib

http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/

Urlgrabber is highspeed rewrite of urllib supporting advanced HTTP download functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

Urllib closes connection itself after finishing urlopen, fp.close() just closes filebuffer, which holds retrieved info:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> fp = urllib.urlopen('http://www.httpbin.org/ip')
>>> fp.read()
0: '{"origin": "::ffff:92.242.181.219"}'
>>> fp.close()
```

There are many good http libraries:

- [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) - easy http-client, built around urlib2/httplib
- [tornado asyncclient](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/httpclient.html) - very light and async interface, mainly to make simple REST requests.
- [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) - fastest and most powerful networking library, supports another protocols, there also exist curls modules,which are ported to [tornado](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/curl_httpclient.py) and  [gevent](https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent-curl)
- i am currently building profilers for those libraries: [source](https://bitbucket.org/timgluz/httpclient/wiki/Home) - there will be speed and memory comparison also.

another choices:

- [twisted webclient](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.html) - grownup async library
- [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) - traditional library for opening URLs
- [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) - HTTP protocol client
- [Doug Hellman's list of Internet and networking modules](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/internet_protocols.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

To close the connection you can use the with statement. In that way you ensure a proper closure of the connection, closing even in a case of exception. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522636/should-i-call-close-after-urllib-urlopen) for a better explanation

Answer (score -1):

Since it isn't mentioned yet: [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) is great (although one of it's great points is reusing persistent (keep-alive) connections rather than closing them)

As for closing the connection: what is it exactly that you're trying to achieve?

If you want to have the connection closed after the request (or rather, after you get the response), you could add a `Connection: close` header to your request. (see [http spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.10)). This will cause the server to close the connection (if it's a well-behaved server at least. I think with httplib2 this will also cause the connection to be closed (by the client) in case server doesn't behave as expected. I don't know about the other libs)