# Under what circumstances urllib2 will be much much slower than IE8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

My code is very simple.

```
import urllib2

fs = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.abc.com')
ofile = open('output.txt','rb')
for b in fs.read():
  ofile.write(b)
ofile.close()
fs.close()
```

Okay. Now I run the program in IDLE and paste the URL directly in IE8. Suprisingly, IE8 returns the entire page way much much much faster than the program.

I suppose maybe my program should be more 'browser' like. While I don't have Wireshark available on this installation, what can I do to speed up my Python program?

Answer (score 1):

http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/ is much faster as I found from this post [Python Better network API than urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191337/python-better-network-api-than-urllib)

Comment: My life will be better because of urlgrabber