# Do objects created by urllib2.urlopen() represent a constant connection?

Tags: python, urllib2

In the following code, is the connection to the remote server held open until `close()`  is called or is it recreated every time `read()` is called? In the following code I do see a new network communication happens every time `read()` is called, rather than the remote file being buffered as soon as `urlopen()` is called.

```
import urllib2

handle = urllib2.urlopen('http://download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip')
while True:
    buff = handle.read(64*1024) # Is a new connection to the server created here?
    if len(x) == 0:
        break
handle.close()
```

Comment: No, there would only be a single connection. What tool are you using to look at connections? netstat?

Answer (score 0):

Try running wireshark or fiddler and look at port 80 with nothing else running.  Run your program and see what traffic you get.  Should answer your question.