# Is it possible to "refresh" a connection created with urllib2.urlopen?

Tags: python, urllib2, urlopen

I am fetching data from a URL using `urllib2.urlopen`:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
...
conn = urlopen(url)
data = conn.read()
conn.close()
```

Suppose the data did not "come out" as I had expected.

What would be the best method for me to read it again?

I am currently repeating the whole process (open, read, close).

Is there a better way (some sort of connection-refresh perhaps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `urlopen` on a URL, Python makes an HTTP GET request and returns the response; each of these request-response pairs are by nature separate connections. You have to repeat the process for every URL you want to request, [although you don't *really* have to close your urlopen response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522636/should-i-call-close-after-urllib-urlopen).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. BTW, the "although you don't really have to close your urlopen response" statement is not correct according to the redirected link.

Answer (score 2):

No, [repeating the process](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-February/566702.html) is the only way to get new data.

Answer (score 0):

you chould close urllib after used to refresh when you open early

try:

import json, urllib
while 1 :
    url='http://project/JsonVanner.php'
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())
    for x in data : 
        print x['Etat']
        if (x['Etat'] == 'OFF'):
        print('vanne fermer')
        print((int(x['IDVanne'])*10)+0)
        else : 
        print('vanne ouverte')
        print((int(x['IDVanne'])*10)+1)
    response.close()