# IOError when Using Urllib to Download Pics

Tags: python, urllib

Can anyone help me on the issue of downloading multiple files? For a while, it will stop me with **IOError** and told me connection attempt failed. I tried to use *time.sleep* function to sleep for random seconds but it doesn't help. And when I re-run the code, it starts to download files again. Any solutions?

[image: IO_Error]

```
import urllib
import time
import random

index_list=["index#1","index#2",..."index#n"]

for n in index_list:
    u=urllib.urlopen("url_address"+str(n)+".jpg")
    data=u.read()   
    f=open("tm"+str(n)+".jpg","wb")
    f.write(data)
    t=random.uniform(0,1)*10
    print "system sleep time is ", t, " seconds"
    time.sleep(t)
```

Comment: What’s the exact error message?

Comment: Just added my error screen.

Comment: Can you open it using a browser like firefox or opera?

Comment: Yes. I also edited my index_list by starting from where the error stopped me and re-run the code and it works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that the error is caused by not closing the connection properly ([should I call close() after urllib.urlopen()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522636/should-i-call-close-after-urllib-urlopen#comment39480273_1522662)).
It also is better practice to close, therefore you should close `f` as well.
You could also use Python's `with` statement.

```
import urllib
import time
import random

index_list = ["index#1", "index#2", ..."index#n"]

for n in index_list:
    # The str() function call isn't necessary, since it's a list of strings
    u = urllib.urlopen("url_address" + n + ".jpg")
    data = u.read()
    u.close()
    with open("tm" + n + ".jpg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(data)
    t = random.uniform(0, 1) * 10
    print "system sleep time is ", t, " seconds"
    time.sleep(t)
```

If the problem still occurs and you can't provide further information, you may try [`urllib.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

Comment: Can I follow up with the question about difference between function urllib.urlopen() and urllib.urlretrieve() in this case. Are they inter-changeable?

Comment: They are pretty similar. `urlopen(...)` returns a read-only file-like object, while `urlretrieve(...)` returns a tuple `(filename, headers)`.
They can be used inter-changeable as far as I know, but I'd say that  `urlretrieve(...)` is rather for "downloading" and writing to the disk, and `urlopen(...)` for reading content.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not closing the connections properly, so the server sees too many open connections? Try to do a u.close() after reading the data in the loop.

Comment: The problem is gone after I re-boot my laptop. Guess I just kept my laptop open for too long for it to operate properly.