# close the ftp connection after using urlretrieve

Tags: python, urllib, six, urlretrieve

```
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve    
urlretrieve('ftp://ftp.cdc.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.dailyavgs/surface/air.sig995.1949.nc', filename='C:\\desktop\\')
```

Do I need to close the ftp connection after using urlretrieve like this? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `urlretrieve`will do that for you. If you were using `urlopen`, you should/could close the connection (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522636/should-i-call-close-after-urllib-urlopen)), but `urlretrieve` handles this four you as a convenient wrapper.

Internally, `urlretrieve` uses an `URLOpener` instance, which calls `close` when its reference count drops to 0, which is at the end of the `urlretrieve` call.