# How do you send an HTTP Get Web Request in Python?

Tags: python, http, streamreader, webrequest

I am having trouble sending data to a website and getting a response in Python. I have seen similar questions, but none of them seem to accomplish what I am aiming for.

This is my C# code I'm trying to port to Python:

```
    static void Request(Uri selectedUri)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(selectedUri);
        request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = BindIPEndPointCallback;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Timeout = (int)Timeout.TotalMilliseconds;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = (int)Timeout.TotalMilliseconds;
        request.CachePolicy = CachePolicy;
        request.UserAgent = UserAgent;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                File.WriteAllText(UrlFileName, responseText.Trim(), Encoding.ASCII);
            }
        }
     }
```

Here is my attempt in Python:

```
def request():
web = httplib.HTTPConnection('https://someurl.com');
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
web.request("GET", "/heartbeat.jsp", headers);
response = web.getresponse();
stream = ""; #something is wrong here
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python

Comment: That question was posted before the requests library existed.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

```
import urllib2
content = urllib2.urlopen(some_url).read()
print content
```

Also you can use [httplib](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/httplib.html)

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("HEAD","/index.html")
res = conn.getresponse()
print res.status, res.reason
# Result:
200 OK
```

or the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
r.status_code
# Result:
200
```

Comment: Ah, a problem I had was that I needed to send the request with httplib. Thanks!

Comment: The httplib module has been renamed to http.client in Python 3.0

Comment: In Python 3, replace `urllib2` with `urllib.request`.

Answer (score 7):

In Python, you can use `urllib2` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) to do all of that work for you.

Simply enough:

```
import urllib2
f =  urllib2.urlopen(url)
print f.read()
```

Will print the received HTTP response.

To pass GET/POST parameters the `urllib.urlencode()` function can be used. For more information, you can refer to the [Official Urllib2 Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html)

Comment: So like, I could type "print urllib2.urlopen(url, array of data).read()" ?

Comment: yes. The output of the read() function is a string that you can print, assign to a variable, etc

Comment: In Python 3, replace `urllib2` with `urllib.request`.