# How to go through a txt file and send requests with certain data

Tags: python, python-requests

I am making a bot that collects users from instagram. So far my program gives me this output on a txt file.
How can I make python go through that and send a get requests using those specific id numbers?

```
LAST QUERY KEY BELOW
AQBLcJ2aIfiorfl1eraIX_g7PH-_ . 
H_poHpXHw1U2rhE4CV7H_nExtvEx05HKwD_2T6rPlcBehKB8FdG3QdKudTMUJl- 
qm6w9jjKJZrkzveEq9Q

ID NUMBERS: 1528791413      USERNAMES: ashleyzarrelli
ID NUMBERS: 5884571287      USERNAMES: kenyattacharmette
ID NUMBERS: 4110147842      USERNAMES: bihotza18
ID NUMBERS: 1917169763      USERNAMES: jenny_in_thecity
ID NUMBERS: 221371076      USERNAMES: grace_richardson97
ID NUMBERS: 6215684919      USERNAMES: bruce_the_little_big_dog
ID NUMBERS: 4762932342      USERNAMES: chickpea_chicks
ID NUMBERS: 6276498249      USERNAMES: bean3199
ID NUMBERS: 3117458992      USERNAMES: buziks.blog
ID NUMBERS: 417125559      USERNAMES: kristieannensley
ID NUMBERS: 416679367      USERNAMES: mavie_noelle
ID NUMBERS: 2165157745      USERNAMES: agent_phoo
```

Comment: show what code you have written and any research you have done

Answer (score 1):

You can extract ID numbers through `re.split(":? ", "string")` to cover corner cases in your data sample, then use `requests` to build the `GET` requests.

The following stack overflow question can be of extra help. [What is the quickest way to HTTP GET in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178483/how-do-you-send-an-http-get-web-request-in-python). More information about `re` and regular expressions can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#)

```
import re
import requests

data_file = open('data.txt','r') # update to reflect location of your .txt file
your_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/posts' # update to reflect your target url

req_list =[]

for line in data_file:
    temp = re.split(":? ", line)
    if len(temp) > 2:
        if (temp[0],temp[1]) == ("ID","NUMBERS"):
            req_list.append(requests.get(your_url, params={'id': temp[2]}))        

print(req_list)
data_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that **file.txt** contains all the info that you posted. Try to use the ***requests*** python module to do the GET request.
I believe that this is the code what you need:

```
import requests

a = open("file.txt")
for li in a.readlines():
    line = li.split(' ')
    if line[0] == 'ID':
        r = requests.get('https://api.example.com/user', params={'id': line[0]})
        print(r.status_code)
```