# Python - sending http requests as strings

Tags: python, http, get

How can I send HTTP requests as string with python? something like this:

```
r = """GET /hello.htm HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: www.stackoverflow.com
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive"""

answer = send(r)
print answer  #  gives me the response as string
```

Comment: Have you searched in google?...Plenty of examples there...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#examples

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming python 3, it is recommended that you use [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).
But since you specifically ask for providing the HTTP message as a string,
I assume you want to do low level stuff, so you can also use [http.client](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html):

```
import http.client
connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('www.python.org')

connection.request('GET', '/')
response = connection.getresponse()
print(response.status)
print(response.msg)
answer = response.read()
print(answer)
```

Comment: how is the r variable used?

Comment: You can use request building methods on the connection object like `putheader`. See the linked documentation