# boto3 equivalent to boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

In regular boto 2.38 I used to access instance metadata (e.g. get current stack-name), through boto's

```
boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()
```

Is there an equivalent in boto3, or do I need to go to the down level direct http address to fetch metadata about the running instance?

Answer (score 18):

Nope, still no equivalent in boto3, just hit this  gap myself.
They have an open  feature request for this https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/313 that references this question.

As for workarounds,
you can  continue to use `boto.utils` or use `urllib`/`urllib2` to do the HTTP requests manually ie.

```
# Python2
import urllib2
instanceid = urllib2.urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').read()

# Python3
import urllib.request
instanceid = urllib.request.urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').read().decode()
```

see [What is the quickest way to HTTP GET in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python) for a quick intro on urllib and http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-categories for the URI structure of the metadata service.

Comment: is this *still* true?! siiiiiiigh

Comment: @dwanderson Unfortunately Yes !

Comment: Additionally you can use the  adamchainz/ec2-metadata package. It would have to be pip installed so is perhaps not ideal for Lambda but this package is simple to use.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the third-party library [ec2-metadata](https://github.com/adamchainz/ec2-metadata#ec2metadatasessionnone).

Here an example from the [docs](https://github.com/adamchainz/ec2-metadata#ec2metadatasessionnone) showing how to get your EC2 region:

```
  pip install ec2-metadata

  >>> from ec2_metadata import ec2_metadata
  >>> print(ec2_metadata.region)
  us-east-1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch specific metadata from the the `IMDSFetcher` in `botocore`:

```py
from botocore.utils import IMDSFetcher

IMDSFetcher()._get_request("/latest/meta-data/instance-type", None).text
```

This will also work on instances where IMDSv2 is enforced.

Comment: This does not work fir IMDSv2 enforced enviroments. as a third argument `token=IMDSFetcher()._fetch_metadata_token()` must be given.

otherwise this is the only valid answer to the origin question!