# Is there a way to obtain the instance id within an ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, backend

I try to launch a service on ec2 instance. the service is supposed to send out the id of the instance. I know this could be obtained using something like `curl http://0.0.0.0/latest/meta-data`. is there any other ways that you could directly get the meta data maybe from the instance shell or some APIs in python?

Answer (score 18):

Amazon EC2 [instance metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) can be accessed via:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

To retrieve the ID of the instance from which that request is made:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/
```

This can be retrieved by curl, wget, web browser or **anything that makes a call to retrieve an HTTP page**.

If you wish to do it programmatically, here's some code from [boto3 equivalent to boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733852/174777):

```
# Python2
import urllib2
instanceid = urllib2.urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').read()

# Python3
import urllib.request
instanceid = urllib.request.urlopen('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id').read().decode()
```

There is also a [`boto.utils.get_instance_metadata()` call in boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/boto.html#boto.utils.get_instance_metadata) (but not boto3) that returns the instance metadata as a nested Python dictionary.

Comment: That's really useful!! thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @WangNick, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.