# How to retrieve data from the Github API in a python script?

Tags: python, web, github

I'm fairly new to any sort of web programming and need help with gathering data from the Github search API. How to I go get the array at https://api.github.com/search/users?q=tom+repos:%3E42+followers:%3E1000 from inside a script? or use a GET /search/user?

Would I do something along the lines of Users[Num_users] = GET api.github.con/search/users?

The github API returns a array of objects (JSON I believe?).

Thank you so much!

Comment: You're on the right track, just use this to make the GET request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why roll your own? Use a prebuilt module:

```
https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub
```

List of Python api's from  https://developer.github.com/libraries/

```
PyGithub
Pygithub3
libsaas
github3.py
sanction
agithub
githubpy
octohub
Github-Flask
torngithub
```