# Updater for Python Application

Tags: python

I'm currently developing a small tool that's supposed to let players of a particular game customize their game way quicker thn actually browsing through the game files, making changes to each and any .ini file. However that is not the matter.
I'd like to get a function going to update my application within itself where there i have a function to download a .zip with the most recent version of my application and unzip it onto the app's directory.

However i need some sort of checkig mechanism to determine rather there's a new version of my app or not. As for that matter, i've uploaded both a .html aswell as a .txt with just a 0 in it which would then be changed to a 1 and uploaded to the web server in case there's an update.

So my question is how you'd go through this as in how would you read the text of the .txt file for example and determine rather it's 0 or 1 in so if the result is 1, it'll go over to downloading the newest version.

Any input is welcome,

Best regards,

Comment: 1) Make an http request with a library of your choice 2) `if response == '1':`...

Comment: mind further explainung 1) ?

Comment: You said your file is on a web server. Do you know how to get data from a web server?

Comment: not quite. havent gone deep into that so far

Comment: Worth a thought, then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python

Comment: that actually worked quite flawlesly yet it does give me : b'0' when i call print on it instead of just 0. any heads up ?

Comment: [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: Thank you a lot. Workel like a charm now