# Broken utf-8 encoding with requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, unicode-string

I am using requests to fetch data from a resp API. 
The problem is that when I try to convert the response to UTF-8 it results in some broken characters, e.g.,

if I use `response.text` I get

```
response.content = {"description":"Golden Cã£o Mb Adulto 3kg F"}
```

if I use `response.content` I get

```
response.content = {"description":"Golden C\xc3\xa3\xc2\xa3o Mb Adulto 3kg F"}
```

I tried to change the request encode using `response.encoding = 'utf-8'`, `response.encoding = 'latin-1'`, and many others before the `response.text`.
I tried `response.decode('utf-8')` and others decoding as well. In this case I have `{"description":"Golden Cã£o Mb Adulto 3kg F"}`

I have many other things in this response, if I use
`response.text.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` I can fix some of these broken caracteres but for the above example I get this error

> {UnicodeDecodeError}'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes ...: invalid continuation byte

I tried a lot of other things, but I could not fix this. I need some help.

---

**Edit:**
Server's response headers

```
{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
  'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
  'Content-Length': '1603',
  'Connection': 'close'
}
```

For the exemple above the result should be

```
{"description":"Golden Cão Mb Adulto 3kg F"}
```

---

**EDIT:** Solved
It turns out the error was in the server side. The server was corrupting some characters when saving them.

Comment: Does the request work when you issue it in a browser? In other words, does the data look all-right? What are the server's response headers?

Comment: I added the header response to my question. There is a swagger that I use to small queries, and there it works.

Comment: There where 3 questions in my comment and you managed to ignore two of them.

Comment: Sorry, 
Does the request work when you issue it in a browser? In other words, does the data look all-right?
Yes and yes. 
 What are the server's response headers?
added to the post.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to make sure that the server does not deliver broken data. Can you also post what the data is supposed to look like when it's not broken?

Comment: For the example I gave, it should be
` {"description":"Golden Cão Mb Adulto 3kg F"} `
But I notice also errors to decode `í` it is decoded as `Ã­-`, `ç` as `Ã§`, `Á` as `Ã`

Comment: Yes, that's because of incorrectly decoding the incoming bytes. `\xc3\xa3\xc2\xa3` is a very curious byte sequence. `C3 A3` is UTF-8 for [LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e3/index.htm), which seems correct. But `C2 A3` is nothing useful, really. Strange. (Well, it is the [POUND SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm), so the value `requests.text` is giving you is correct, but the fact that you say there is no pound sign in the browser is strange.) Is the URL you work with publicly available so I can test it from my end?

Comment: Sorry it is not public. But I noticed that too. Then I found [this article](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html). There is a table mapping `ã£` as `ã`

Comment: I think I fixed, after your comment I realized that the first sequence is the character i want and the second is "garbage". the second sequence, sometimes, is not recognized as UTF-8. So, I just ignored those.
`response.text.encode('latin-1').decode('utf8','ignore')` seems to work.

Comment: I'm not really sure that that is the solution because the browser does not show garbage. It seems pretty "hacky" to me, I'd not be so sure that you don't create a bunch of new errors this way.

Comment: You are right,  there is still some flaws. but it worked for a good part of the result. For example, it worked for  `ã£` but nor for  `Ã£`

Comment: That's what I expected. Your current attempt is not useful. I'd like to take the requests module out of the equation. Please use [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645318/18771) to download the data and add the raw result you get from there to your question.

Comment: The error is in the server side, I mean, there are more than one entry 
"Golden Cão Mb Adulto 3kg F" and one of those has the broken character. When I said that in the browser was working I was looking at the wrong entry.

Comment: All-right, I suspected it might be broken data. Not a lot you can do on the client side, then. The `requests` module does the right thing.

Comment: @Rafael Would you edit this to your question or add as an (accepted) answers, so that others can find this? Currently it is buried in the comments.

Comment: I added to the question. Tks