# Python - send headers using wget module with headers

Tags: python, windows, wget

I'm trying to download a file (a discord profile picture to be precise) using the Discord API to get the URL. however, the wget module in python returns a 403 forbidden. I would edit the source of the wget module, but don't know where the source is.

Comment: Try changing your user agent by adding the header `User:Agent : Mozilla/5.0` or something along those lines?

Comment: Why wget? Why not requests? Much more straightforward.

Comment: seems it's not possible to add Headers using wget module.  Use `request` or `urllib3` instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python