# Model implementation in production with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, implementation, tcp

I built a machine learning model of binary classification in python.

It works on my laptop (e.g. command line tool). Now I want to deploy it in production on a separate server in my company. It has to take inputs from another server (C# application), make some calculations and return outputs back to it.

My question is what are the best practices of doing such thing in production? As I know it can be done through TCP/IP connection.

I am new in this field and I don't know the terms used here. 
So can anybody guide me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on your infrastructure and how can the other application (C#) can communicate.

The easiest way in my opinion would be through a REST API (http request). There are some tools in different languages to create REST endpoints easily and request REST endpoints.

For example, in python, you can request the content of a URL like this:
[What is the quickest way to HTTP GET in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python)

But it depends on what you have on the C# side. Can you update the C# code?

Here are a range of solutions:

- REST API: need to expose REST endpoints on the communicating "service".

  - in C#: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api
  - in python, I would recommend django framework if you need to create a server (but if the python only request things and don't serve as a server, you may not need it)
- message queue like rabbitmq or zeromq, but it requires an external service to manage queues and messages
- TCP/IP socket like you suggested, but it requires to manage yourself those connections