# How get the parameters from the url path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, parameters, urlopen

Introductory tags: **[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)** | **[python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)** | **[url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url)** | **[parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parameters)** | **[urlopen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urlopen)**

Used language: **Python 3.x**

Used modules: **urlopen** | **urllib.request**

Status: **Not yet resolved**

## Description of the problem:

I have url:

```
 http://mapy.cz/#mm=TTtP@x=133054720@y=135947904@z=13
```

and it redirects me (in web browser) to another url:

```
 https://mapy.cz/zakladni?x=14.412346408814274&y=50.08612581835152&z=13
```

I want to get the parameters *x* and *y* from the **path**.

```
 x = 14.412346408814274
 y = 50.08612581835152
```

*(Geographic coordinates in decimal degrees.)*

When I use:

```
 from urllib.request import urlopen

 url = "http://mapy.cz/#mm=TTtP@x=133168128@y=133141248@z=13"
 print(urlopen(url).url)
```

It will return me:

```
 https://mapy.cz/
```

When I use:

```
with urlopen(url) as conn:
    newUrl = conn.geturl()        
    print (newUrl)
```

It will return me:

```
 https://mapy.cz/
```

When I use:

```
with urlopen(url) as conn:
    print (conn.info())
```

It will return me:

```
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 03 Jun 2018 23:24:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Sun, 03 Jun 2018 23:24:31 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

When I use:

```
with urlopen(url) as conn:
    print (conn.__dict__)
```

It will return me:

```
{'fp': <_io.BufferedReader name=1404>, 'debuglevel': 0, '_method': 'GET', 'headers': <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x000000000DD48518>, 'msg': 'OK', 'version': 11, 'status': 200, 'reason': 'OK', 'chunked': True, 'chunk_left': None, 'length': None, 'will_close': True, 'code': 200, 'url': 'https://mapy.cz/'}
```

There is no mention of the parameters/path behind the slash.
Neither the original url nor the following url.

When I use code from [What is the quickest way to HTTP GET in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python):

```
import urllib.request
contents = urllib.request.urlopen("url").read()
```

It will return me:

```
'raw html...'
```

I don't want to open/download the html and mining those parameters from html.

Comment: In general, if uropen, requests, etc. acts differently than your browser, I'd first suspect the User-Agent header -- just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `requests` (which you should) here is the solution for your specific URL:

```
import requests

URL = 'http://mapy.cz/#mm=TTtP@x=133054720@y=135947904@z=13'

response = requests.get(URL)

if response.history:
    print("Request was redirected")
    for resp in response.history:
        print((resp.status_code, resp.url,))
        # getting x, y and z
        parts = resp.url.split('@')
        x = parts[1].split('=')[1]
        y = parts[2].split('=')[1]
        z = parts[3].split('=')[1]
        print("X {} Y {} Z {}".format(x, y, z))

    print("Final destination:")
    print((response.status_code, response.url,))
else:
    print("Request was not redirected")
```

Comment: It doesn't return what OP expected (it only splits the same thing in the input URL).

Comment: I ran it and returned the exact values for `x, y, z`. What values did you get?

Comment: I got this: `X 133054720 Y 135947904 Z 13`

Comment: This code return me:

     Request was redirected
     (301, 'http://mapy.cz/#mm=TTtP@x=133054720@y=135947904@z=13')

     X 133054720 Y 135947904 Z 13

     Final destination:

     (200, 'https://mapy.cz/')
     http://mapy.cz/#mm=TTtP@x=133054720@y=135947904@z=13

*response.status_code* changes (301 -> 200) but path behind the slash is the same.