# How does Python make a HTTP GET request

Tags: python, browser, get

I am new to Python and I know this would be a Day-1 question - but any help here is highly appreciated.
I want to understand how Python (or any language) makes a HTTP GET request and has access to the page source. Does it use the default browser engine available in the OS?

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing Python-specific, and no, you don't use any existing browser to write an HTTP client.

As to "how is a HTTP client implemented", the question is way too broad, but you can just look at Python's source code (it's open source) to find out: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/urllib/request.py