# Parse a json request using json module of python

Tags: python, json

I want to parse json request 
(GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json?count=2&screen_name=episod) using python. please tell me how to do that.

Comment: what specific problem are you facing? This is too broad.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+json

Comment: Have you looked into python's `requests` library?

Comment: this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645312/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-http-get-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`requests.get()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) to make a GET request to your URL and get the JSON string:

```
from requests import get

URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/list.json?count=2&screen_name=episod"

res = get(URL).text

print(res)
# {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

print(type(res))
# <class 'str'>
```

Then you can use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert the JSON string into a python dictionary:

```
from json import loads

json_dict = loads(res)

print(json_dict)
# {'errors': [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]}

print(type(json_dict))
# <class 'dict'>
```

Which you can iterate and parse the information you want.

Comment: can you please help me with the authentication as I am getting the same error u mentioned. here is the authentication I have used                                                  
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)